# Calling filtered line from a range variable

Tags: vba, excel

I filter my table in Excel with VBA and save it in a range variable. E.g.: I had 1000 fields and, after filtering, it had only 200. I saved the data in a range and made a random to select one number in this range.

After this, I wanted to change informations at the line filtered. However, I don't know how do this. For example, if I use `Cells(Line, 10)` the vba consider all lines and print out range.

How can I change only the filtered cell by number or address?

```
Dim Rng As Range
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AE" & tlast_row).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="teste"
Set Rng= Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
tSelCell = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, RngC.Count)
Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(tSelCell, 3) = "TEST" '< Here is the problem
```

Comment: **RngC** must be **Set** before *RngC.Count* can be used.

Comment: The RngC is the same Rng - Sorry by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we filter for "Happy":

[image]

The visible cells form a **disjoint range.**  To make a random pick from a disjoint range, we first create an array of the visible cell addresses and then make a random pick from that array:

```
Option Base 1

Sub PickARandomVisibleRow()
    Dim rDisjoint As Range, ary() As Variant, NrD As Long
    Dim tSelCell As Long
    Set rDisjoint = Range("A2:A24").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    NrD = rDisjoint.Count
    ReDim ary(1)

    i = 1
    For Each r In rDisjoint
        If i = 1 Then
        Else
            ReDim Preserve ary(i)
        End If
        ary(i) = r.Address
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    msg = ""
    For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & i & vbTab & ary(i)
    Next i
    MsgBox msg

    tSelCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, UBound(ary))
    msg = "Random Pick item: " & tSelCell & " which is cell: " & ary(tSelCell)
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Comment: **Perfect** Gary - Thank you so much, this will help me a lot. Have a great Weekend!